# Find the element that does not fit the pattern

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence, sequence

These 12 elements form a set with a certain pattern, but there is one element that does not fit. Which one is that?

[image]

HINT

> The pattern is similar to this pattern having twelve elements too:  2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35

HINT 2

> There is a rule in the two distinct but similar patterns. For the number pattern it is: "3n+2".
>  The rule is not exactly the same in the letter set, but the item that breaks the pattern has a correspondence (one on one logical correspondence) in the number set.

Comment: Hi John, is this your own puzzle or did you find it somewhere? If the latter, please could you attribute the source in the question? Otherwise this may end up being closed since all questions from elsewhere need to be fully accredited on this site... Thanks!

Comment: Hi! This is one of my puzzles.

Comment: Hi John, I like this puzzle but it's very hard and no good answers have been posted in 2 weeks. Time for a hint?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with rot13(Punatvat gur yrggref vagb ahzoref?)

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the

> First one, SRR is the odd one out.

Because,

> Each of the other strings can begin an English word. SCRape, APple, CALm, FIAt, CHLorine, DOCtor, RENt, EMPire, MIEn, COal, MEIosis to name some examples.

Comment: nice observation but does not really use anything from the pattern other than letters